# Use different database structs in global configuration struct

Tags: go

I have a global config for most settings (e.g. Logfiles) which I use in all Projects, for example:

```
project config

type Config struct {
    Logfile string
    Loglevel string
    Database *database.Database
}
```

The config itself has its own project, the database has its own projects and the implementation is done in its own project. (So I have config project, database project, and app project).

I want every Project to implement the database itself since all of them have different functions attached to it. Since I don't want multiple fields for every database, I have a minimum interface which is satisfied by all Database Implementations

```
project database

// This interface is referenced by the Config struct using *database.Database
type Database interface {
    InitDatabase() error
}

type AppDatabase interface {
    InitDatabase() error // To satisfy the Database interface
    AdditionalFunction1() 
    AdditionalFunction2()
}

type OtherAppDatabase interface {
    InitDatabase() error
    OtherFunc1() 
}
```

When I want to implement the database, I want to assign the new database struct to the (project-) global configuration (e.g config.Database).

However, this does not work as I cannot assign the new struct (which implements the database interface) to the conf.Database interface, e.g.

```
project app 

type OtherAppDatabase struct {
    *sql.DB
}

func (db *OtherAppDatabase) InitDatabase() error {
    conf := config.GetConfig() // this just returns the global config file

    conf.Database = d // This does not work [1]
}

func (db *OtherAppDatabase) OtherFunc1() {}
```

[1]: Cannot use 'db' (type *OtherAppDatabase) as type *database.Database in assignment
Inspection info: Reports incompatible types in binary and unary expressions.

Is there a way to keep one database field in the global config and assign the specific database to it as needed?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: If you make the "global database" an interface, then you can assign any value to it that satisfies the interface. However, this will lead to another problem: Only the methods in the interface will be accessible, without doing a type assertion. So TL;DR; your design seems broken.

Comment: This works with Type assertion in each command, is there a way to save the asserted interface in the original interface?

Comment: No. Go is statically typed.